# How to change category page layout in Magento?

Tags: magento

My problem is I want to change my category page layout similar as homepage I tried a lot but didn't get the answer.

Answer (score 11):

However, the best way to do this is to not edit catalog.xml, but page.xml

under  , edit the first block you see there:

```
<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
```

change this to:

```
<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-right.phtml">
```

for further detail follow this link
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/16838/

Answer (score 10):

Login to admin side

Catelog -> manage Categories -> Choose your category

Then on the tab section select Custom Design.

Change the Page Layout  as what ever you want.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if I understand your question. Anyways...

You can edit the category view at template/catalog/category/view.phtml.

If you require to use the 3 column layout like the home page, you need to assign the 3 column template in the catalog.xml file.

Comment: By the way, the website is very slow! Took ages to load.

Answer (score 1):

Edit catalog.xml from your /app/design/frontend/**your_theme**/default/layout/catalog.xml and in **default block** add a new **reference** block

```
<default>
...
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
...
</default>
```

In this way, you overwrite the root block in page.xml (the main layout file Magento loads)

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension located at this [thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/33307/) that allows you to set the page layout for your categories

Answer (score -6):

Run the below given script. It will set the value “'three_columns'” to the field “Page Layout” of all categories.

```
$write          =      Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$updateQry  =   "UPDATE catalog_category_entity_varchar SET value='three_columns' WHERE attribute_id='61' ";
$write->query($updateQry);
```

Comment: What if the attribute ID doesn't match yours? This is not a good answer.